# ImageButton automatic scaling issue

Tags: android, resolution, imagebutton

I'm trying to troubleshoot my code for a small form factor device and the ImageButtons I'm using in my RelativeLayout seem to get automatically scaled larger somehow.  I've tried various methods of preventing them from scaling, but none of them have worked.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to see Density Considerations for Preventing from Scaling.

The easiest way to avoid pre-scaling is to `put the resource in a resource directory` with the nodpi configuration qualifier. For example:

```
res/drawable-nodpi/icon.png
```

When the system uses the icon.png bitmap from this folder, it does not scale it based on the current device density.

From
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
android:maxHeight
android:maxWidth
```

Can you tell us what methods you've tried so far?